How to use the host name for generation in maven archetype?
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName returns a String in a Java program.
In Win10 its the same value you get from hostname command or from echo %COMPUTERNAME% in a CMD window.
How can I use this string in a maven archetype when generating a maven project from it?
E.g. In the archetype specification I tried
#set($hostname = $env.COMPUTERNAME)
...
void my_function_at_${hostname} ()
...

but it did not work out as expected.
